# What are the type primitives in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

#### What are the type primitives in Dart / Flutter ?

I'm expecting a list that has things like `String`, `Class`, `Function`(?) in it.

I can't seem to find this anywhere in the [Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides).

Specifically actually right now I'm writing something where I want to pass in a function as a parameter, so I'm trying to figure out what the function/method type is (assuming that is a thing), but more generally I want the reference to all the Dart type primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:
[dart:core library](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/dart-core-library.html):

> Built-in types, collections, and other core functionality for every
>   Dart program.

Specifically this part: [Classes](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/dart-core-library.html#classes), where you could find:

> **String** A sequence of UTF-16 code units. [...]
>
> **Object** The base class for all Dart objects. [...]
>
> **Function** The base class for all function types. [...]

Comment: Other Dart primitive types are int, double, and bool.

Answer (score 15):

Most Dart types are just class/interface types. Unlike Java, Dart does not have "primitive" value types that are not interfaces, so in Dart `int`, `double`, `String`, `bool` and `Null` normal interfaces which are subtypes of `Object?` (and of `Object` except for `Null`), and the values are just normal objects.

Dart does have some *types* and *type constructors* which are not class/interface types, or which have specific rules preventing you from implementing them. In particular:

- `void` - Equivalent to `Object?`, but you're not allowed to use the value. You can return any value from a `void` function, but no-one is supposed to use it.
- `dynamic` - Equivalent to `Object?`, but without static type checking. You can cast any value to `dynamic`, and then use it as any type, and you get run-time errors if you make a mistake.
- `Never` - an empty subtype of all types. A function returning `Never` is guaranteed to throw.
- `type Function(argTypes)` - A function type. Some values are functions. They're still objects, but are not class/interface instances. Subtypes of the interfaces `Function` and `Object`.
- `FutureOr<type>` - a supertype of both `type` and `Future<type>`.
- `type?` - a nullable type. A supertype of both `type` and `Null`.
- EDIT: And now record types like `(int, int)` and `({int x, int y})`.

Then the following interfaces have restrictions which prevents you from implementing them in your own classes: `Null`, `int`, `double`, `num`, `bool`, `String`, and `Function`.

So, for function types, you write them as, fx, `int Function(int, {int y})`.