# How to cast an object with a generic type

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this small code snippet:

```dart
class A<T> {
  A(this.a);
  
  final T a;
}


void main() {
  final a = A(true);
  print(a);
  print(a as A<bool>);
  
  final b = A<Object>(true);
  print(b);
  print(b as A<bool>);  
}
```

I'm receiving the object `b` from a library/API which is a `A<Object>` (and I don't have control over it), but I know it is actually a `A<bool>` in my specific case. I'm trying to cast it to `A<bool>` (as in my code snippet with `b`). But I get an error saying that `A<Object>` is not a subtype of `A<bool>`.

Here are the logs from the code snippet pasted above:

```
Instance of 'A<bool>'
Instance of 'A<bool>'
Instance of 'A<Object>'
Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'A<Object>': type 'A<Object>' is not a subtype of type 'A<bool>'
```

How can I cast `b` (a `A<Object>`) into a `A<bool>`?

Comment: bool is a primitive, hence not an Object so what you're trying to do is impossible without some workarounds.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I can do `late final Object f; f = true; print(f as bool);` and I don't get any error even though I wrote `f as bool` with `f` of type `Object`.

Comment: Also, I get the same result if I replace `A<Object>` with `A<dynamic>`: `Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'A<dynamic>': type 'A<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'A<bool>'`

Comment: Actually now that i look into it bool is a class so now I'm intrigued. 
print(a as A<bool>); <-- this casts a bool to another bool so it's unnecessary.
However the bool class in dart is a wrapper for bool.fromEnvironment(String) which is a factory method. If this under-the-hood method does something to prevent the cast, I'm sure i don't know.

Comment: @krumpli [Dart does not have primitives.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65073696/)  Everything is an `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I cast `b` (a `A<Object>`) into a `A<bool>`?

You can't.  They're not the same type.

`b` was *constructed* as an `A<Object>`, so its runtime type is `A<Object>`, regardless of whether `b.a` happens to be referring to a `bool`.  A cast with `as` changes the *static* (known to the compiler) type of an object, but you cannot change an object's *runtime* type.  If you want an object with a different runtime type, you must construct a separate object.

Let's consider a slightly different example:

```dart
class C<T> {
  T value;

  C(this.value);
}
```

`C<T>` is the same thing as `A<T>` except that its member is not `final`.  If casting an object with a runtime type of `C<Object>` to `C<bool>` were allowed, then we could have the following:

```dart
final c = C<Object>(true);
final casted = c as C<bool>; // Should this be allowed?
c.value = 'Hello world!'; // Legal since `c.value` is of type `Object`.
bool someBool = casted.value; // ???
```

Arguably the case for casting `A` is different; `A`'s member is `final` and therefore wouldn't lead to the above scenario.  However, I'd expect that that kind of exception would add a lot of complexity and possibly could make things even more confusing.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67223011/

Answer (score 0):

The following code can cast it. dont know if it works in your case.

```
var c = A<bool>(b.a as bool);
/// OR
extension Cast on A<Object> {
  A<bool> cast() => A<bool>(a as bool);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my example is a minimal on to illustrate the issue. I won't be able to do that with a bigger/more complicated object